# Query to find field containing Unicode

Tags: sql, regex, unicode, ascii

I am trying to write a simple query to get all records that contain Unicode/non-ASCII characters in the "description" field:

```
select *
from products
where description <criterion goes here>
```

I can search for specific characters, but what I really want is any field that would fail if it were loaded to a system (or by a driver) that didn't suport Unicode.

It would be nice if there were a regex atom for ASCII, like `\a`, similar to `\d` for digit, `\s` for whitespace, etc, but if there is it has escaped me.

I suspect I am missing something easy or obvious.

This would be for Oracle, Sybase or PostgreSQL.

Comment: http://sniptools.com/databases/finding-non-utf8-values-in-postgresql

Comment: for oracle https://community.oracle.com/thread/1089539?start=0&tstart=0